# Genealogytree of Caligula

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I did my best to reproduce this ancestor tree in the best way [image: (see picture)] but I haven't quite succeeded yet. [image] How can I do it, so that Antonia II is only connected to Drusus I (marriage). How can I expand this branch at Tiberius like on the template? Enclosed my LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\section{Stammbaum des Caligula}
\begin{tikzpicture}


 \genealogytree[template=signpost,
  label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize},]{

  parent{
    p[male]{CLAUDIUS}
    g[male]{Nero}
    parent{
      p[male]{Germanicus}
      c[male]{Nero Germanici}
      c[male]{Drusus III}
      c[male]{CALIGULA}
      c[female]{Drusilla}
      c[female]{Livilla II}
      g[female]{Agrippina II}
      parent{
        c[male]{C. Caesar}
        c[male]{L. Caesar}
        c[male]{Agrippa Postumus}
        g[female]{Agrippina I}
        p[male]{Agrippa}
        parent{
          g[female]{Iulia}
          c[male]{TIBERIUS}
          c[male]{Drusus I}
          parent{
            g[male]{AUGUSTUS}
            p[male]{C. Iulius Caesar}
           }
          p[female]{Livia}
         }
         parent{
          g[female]{Antonia II}
          parent{
            g[female]{Octavia}
           }
          p[male]{M. Antonius}
       }
     }
   }
 }
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please help me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Genealogytree, automates some things, but as many ad hoc pagkages based in tikz, limits the options for high personalization, instead you have basic tikz code to draw almost everything parametric in 2d, in this case helped with positioning tikz library and arrows meta to control the arrow size for relation styles to get the same termination size that is affected by the line size, I use a label node to put gender symbols.

RESULT :

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment cfg
        >={Straight Barb[length=4pt]},
        %Environment Styles
        Male/.style={
            label={[draw,blue,circle,inner sep=1pt]#1:\male}
        },
        Female/.style={
            label={[draw,magenta,circle,inner sep=1pt]#1:\female}
        },
        Parents/.style={line width=0.75 pt},
        Rel1/.style={line width=2 pt,dash pattern= on 7pt off 3pt},
        Dir/.style={line width=2 pt},
        Adop/.style={line width=1 pt,dash pattern= on 7pt off 3pt}
    ]
    
    \path
    node(CIC)[Male=180]{C. Iulius Caesar}
    node(AUG)[Male=180,below= of CIC]{AUGUSTUS}
    node(LIV)[Female=0,right= of AUG]{Livia}
        (AUG) -- (LIV) node[midway](AUGxLIV){$\infty$}
    node(OCT)[Female=180,right= 4.5 of LIV]{Octavia}
    node(MA)[Male=0,right= 2.5 of OCT]{M. Antonius}
        (OCT) -- (MA) node[midway](OCTxMA){$\infty$}
    node(AGR)[Male=180,below left= 2 and 4.5 of AUG]{Agrippa}
    node(IUL)[Female=0,right= of AGR]{Iulia}
        (AGR) -- (IUL) node[midway](AGRxIUL){$\infty$}
    node(TIB)[Male=180,right= 4.5 of IUL]{TIBERIUS}
    node(DRU-I)[Male=180,right=2.5 of TIB]{Drusus I}
    node(ANT-II)[Female=0,right=2 of DRU-I]{Antonia II}
        (DRU-I) -- (ANT-II) node[midway](DRU-IxANT-II){$\infty$}
    node(DRU-II)[Male=180,below left= 2 and -1.5 of TIB]{Drusus II}
    node(LIV-I)[Female=0,right= of DRU-II]{Livilla I}
        (DRU-II) -- (LIV-I) node[midway](DRU-IIxLIV-I){$\infty$}
    node(TIB-G)[Male=180,below= of DRU-IIxLIV-I]{Tiberius Gemellus}
    node(CC)[Male=180,below=6 of AGR]{C. Caesar}
    node(LC)[Male=180,right= of CC]{L. Caesar}
    node(AP)[Male=180,right= of LC,text depth=-\baselineskip,align=center]{Agrippa \\ Postumus}
    node(AGP-I)[Female=180,right= 1.5 of AP]{Agrippina I}
    node(GER)[Male=0,right= 2 of AGP-I]{Germanicus}
        (AGP-I) -- (GER) node[midway](AGP-IxGER){$\infty$}
    node(CAL)[Male=180,below=2 of AGP-I]{CALIGULA}
    node(DRU-III)[Male=180,left= of CAL]{Drusus III}
    node(NG)[Male=180,left=2 of DRU-III]{Nero Germanici}
    node(DRUS)[Female=180,right= of CAL]{Drusilla}
    node(LIV-II)[Female=180,right= of DRUS]{Livilla II}
    node(AGP-II)[Female=180,right= of LIV-II]{Agrippina II}
    node(CLA)[Male=0,right=2 of AGP-II]{CLAUDIUS}
        (AGP-II) -- (CLA) node[midway](AGP-IIxCLA){$\infty$}
    node(NE)[Male=180,below= of AGP-II]{NERO}
    ;
    
    \draw[Parents,<->] (LIV) -- ++(0,0.75) -| (OCT);
    \draw[Parents,<->] (TIB) -- ++(0,0.75) coordinate(T1) -| (DRU-I);
    \draw[Parents,<->] (LIV-I.75) -- ++(0,0.5) coordinate(T2) -| (CLA);
    \draw[Parents,<->] (CC) -- ++(0,0.75) coordinate(T3) -| (AGP-I);
    \draw[Parents,<->] (NG) -- ++(0,0.75) coordinate(T4) -| (AGP-II);
    \draw[Parents,->](TIB.-150) -- (TIB.-150 |- DRU-II.90);
    \draw[Parents,->](DRU-IIxLIV-I) -- (TIB-G);
    \draw[Parents,->](T3 -| LC) -- (LC);
    \draw[Parents,->](T3 -| AP) -- (AP);
    \draw[Parents,->](T4 -| DRU-III) -- (DRU-III);
    \draw[Parents,->](T4 -| CAL) -- (CAL);
    \draw[Parents,->](T4 -| DRUS) -- (DRUS);
    \draw[Parents,->](T4 -| LIV-II) -- (LIV-II);
    \draw[Parents,->](AGP-II) -- (NE);
    
    \draw[Rel1,->]
    (CIC) edge (AUG)
    (AUG) edge (TIB.150)
    (TIB.-15) -- (LIV-I)[shorten >=8pt] --  (GER);
    
    \draw[Dir,->](AUG.-165) -- (IUL.50);
    \draw[Dir,->](LIV) -- (LIV |- T1) -| (DRU-I);
    \draw[Dir,->](OCTxMA) -- (ANT-II);
    \draw[Dir,->](DRU-IxANT-II) -- (DRU-IxANT-II |- T2) -| (GER);
    \draw[Dir,->](AGRxIUL) -- (AGRxIUL |- T3) -| (AGP-I);
    \draw[Dir,->](AGP-IxGER) -- (AGP-IxGER |- T4) -| (CAL);
    
    \draw[Adop,->](AUG.-160) -- (CC.20);
    \draw[Adop,->](AUG.-155) -- (LC.30);
    \draw[Adop,->](AUG.-145) -- (AUG.-145 |- AP.90);
    \draw[Adop,->](CLA.-90) -- (NE);
    
    \draw[Dir] (AGR.180 |- NE.-90) coordinate (T5)-- ++ (1,0) node[anchor=west]{direkte Abstammung};
    \draw[Adop](T5)++(5,0) -- ++ (1,0)node[anchor=west]{Adoption};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**WHY STANDALONE DOCUMENT CLASS ?**
This document class size automatically the canvas and add some border, so you can draw without care about page dimension from your main document because you can import the compiled pdf output within figure environment page using:

`\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{my_tikz_draw_in_standalone_class_file_pdf_output.pdf}`

So the tikz drawing is inported without loosing its vector properties, if the typography differs from your main document, juts copy the lines that defines text styles from your main document to the standalone class tikz drawing.

Comment: Ok wow thank you for help and this drawing. So it is not possible to draw "Antonia II is only connected to Drusus I (marriage)" with genealogytree? That would be great. I'm about to finish drawing this tree, only the other branches are missing.

Comment: Which software you used to draw this?

Comment: [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/) on pdfTex 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.6745 64-bit)

Comment: Great thanks, how much time it took to create this drawing?

Comment: About 50 minutes, which consumes more time is to position the nodes like this in the sample drawing that is almost like half an hour, in addition to naming the nodes and writing their contents, then placing arrows is easier with the names of the nodes and the additional delay is to define the styles and add details can be relative to the complexity, I already knew the typography, and basic methods for all that, but as when I started it took many hours to do it, an interesting manual and Quick that helped me is [visualtikz.](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf)

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the hints, as I thought it will took a long time to draw that from scratch without any experience.

Comment: @JLeonV. Does it support arbitrary mesh structures, not only just the tree structures? For example, imagine building a genealogy with 8 generations, where you have 8 great-grandparents, 16 third-great-grandparents, etc., with their siblings, their siblings' children, and their siblings' grandchildren. The `genealogytree` package does not support it. :-/

Comment: @Oo'-, well basically the example I gave does not use anything from the geneology library, it uses the raw code to make nodes and draw tikz arrows, and therefore it has no limits except the limitations of the topological distribution of connections and the positions according to the number of generations. so it would be good for you to make the query with a clear example of what you want and at least a basic code that works, the precious MWE.